# What do I do to deploy my ERC 20 token

Tags: erc-20

I have a ERC 20 token platform the token: BTZ 
botztoken
and what I am wanting to do is figure out what I can do with 
the tokens as utility tokens to accomplish teams mission which is:
to help veterans and seniors in times of needs. Am putting a community of people together that we want them to share the tokens and earn them by giving and sharing.